# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.actor.CoordinatedShutdown$Reason when upgrading from akka 2.4.9 to 2.5.9

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

we are trying to upgrade the akka 2.4.9 to 2.5.9 after the announcement that akka 2.4.x has reached its EOL.

During the process, we encountered the below error during runtime.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.actor.CoordinatedShutdown$Reason
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 58 more
```

In release notes, it is mentioned that there is new extension for CoordinatedShutdown [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html#coordinated-shutdown)
But the documentation there doesn't mention anything about new jar that needs to included in the build file.

Any idea how to resolve this error.

Comment: Could this be some dependency conflict? Could you somehow share your dependency tree, for example with https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph or by sharing part of your build scripts?

Comment: Arnout Engelen - we are using maven in our projects.  If I do `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections`, will that be helpful?

Comment: Yes, that would be interesting!